# Media Boxes Portfolio - Responsive Grid display image URL in brower URL bar on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I'm using jQuery Media Boxes Portfolio - Responsive Grid for displaying images, it works well but when I click on any image for popup, it's url also get displayed in browser and after that when I click on broswer back button it reopen image popup instead of going to previous page. I checked it in plugin's given example and same issue is there too.

https://codecanyon.net/item/media-boxes-portfolio-responsive-grid/5683020
http://www.castlecodeweb.com/mediaboxes/example/full_width_gallery.html

Here is what it look like when I click on image:

http://prntscr.com/eff2jg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can disabled the hash/deeplinking, is one of their settings, just pass these 2 options in the JS initialization

```
deepLinkingOnPopup: false,
deepLinkingOnFilter: false,
```

and it will look like this example: http://www.castlecodeweb.com/mediaboxes/example/pinterest_style.html as you can see the URL is clean of hash